# Отправка файла через AJAX, $_FILES не приходит

Tags: ajax, файлы, post

Имеется форма

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="f2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

отправлю ее вот таким скриптом

```
<script>
function AjaxFormRequest2(result_id,error,formMain,url) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    formD = new FormData(document.forms.%FORM_ID%);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: formD,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType:'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){}
      success: function(response) {
         document.getElementById(error).innerHTML = response;
      },
      error: function(response) {
         document.getElementById(error).innerHTML = "Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз";
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

*форма отправляется, POST запрос получаю и обрабатываю, а вот print_r($_FILES);*

только что проверил, точнее этот код **вобще не работает**, перепутал и отправлял форму на другую функцию которая только пост запрос отправляет стандартны...

выдает пустой массив... подскажите, где допустил ошибку?

Comment: а разве не  так надо? var formD = ... и еще: type: "POST",

Comment: добавил var , и type: "POST", никакого результата...